# NokiaX java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, nokiax

I was trying to port my app to NokiaX and received this exception

```
05-07 13:00:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 13:00:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mcruiseon.bykegirihindjewadibeta/com.mcruiseon.caregiri.Registration}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mcruiseon.caregiri.Registration
05-07 13:00:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1991)
05-07 13:00:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
```

This project used another project as library, and that project did build and was part of the apk. So why was it not able to find `com.mcruiseon.caregiri.Registration` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I forgot to add `com.google.android.maps.jar` bundled with the NokiaX SDK into the `libs` folder.

The exception is rather misleading.